# Get parent directory name in Node.js

Tags: node.js, path

I am using Node.js, and I want to obtain the parent directory name for a 
file. I have the file `"../test1/folder1/FolderIWant/test.txt"`.

I want to get `"FolderIWant"`.

I have tried:

```
var path = require('path');
var parentDir = path.dirname(filename);
```

But it returns `../test1/folder1/FolderIWant`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[Better use @danielwolf's answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779639/3993662)

---

Use `split()` and `pop()`:

```
path.dirname(filename).split(path.sep).pop()
```

Answer (score 280):

What you want is [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext):

```
path.basename(path.dirname(filename))
```

Answer (score 89):

Daniel Wolf's answer is correct, also if you want the full path of the parent dir:

```
require('path').resolve(__dirname, '..')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const path = require("path")
path.dirname(path.basename(__dirname))
```

Comment: Backwards of https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779639/458321? this didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

`process.mainModule` property is deprecated in `v14.0.0`. If foo.js is run by `node foo.js` (e.g. somedir/foo.js"),

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

result: somedir

[Use require.main instead](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module)

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the answers herein worked somewhat, I found use of the popular [app-root-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path) module a better anchor point from which to specify a path.

```
import { path as arp } from 'app-root-path'
import path from 'path'

const root = path.resolve(arp, '../') // the parent of the root path

export const rootDirname = root
```

Example usage as follows:

```
import { rootDirname } from './functions/src/utils/root-dirname'
import { getJsonFromFile } from './app/utils/get-json-from-file'

const firebaseJson = getJsonFromFile(`${rootDirname}/firebase.json`)
```

Maybe not the best answer here but an option not covered by other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Using node as of 06-2019, I ran into an issue for accessing just `filename`.
So instead, I just modified it a tiny bit and used:

```
path.dirname(__filename).split(path.sep).pop()
```

so now you get the directory name of the current directory you are in and not the full path. Although the previous answers seem to possibly work for others, for me it caused issues as node was looking for a const or a variable but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3):

The typical `__dirname` solution doesn't work in an ESM scope. To move one level higher in the directory tree, I came up with the following solution:

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import path from "path";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
// First find out the __dirname, then resolve to one higher level in the dir tree
const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(__filename), "../");
```

If you only need the absolute directory path the file resides in, you can leave out the `path.resolve()` call.

Answer (score 2):

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)
```

Use this anywhere to get the root directory

Comment: it show error at mainModule. Unresolved variable mainModule

Comment: @usmanimtiaz https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-process-mainmodule-property/

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way without any node modules like the path. You can easily do in the following manner to get the root folder name.

```
var rootFolder = __dirname.split('/').pop();
console.log(rootFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` is an environment variable that tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file.

Get just the parent with this simple code:

```js
let parentFolder = __dirname.split('\\').pop();
```

output of my `__dirname`

```js
console.log({ path: __dirname, parentDirectory: __dirname.split('\\').pop()});
```

```
{ 
path: 'C:\\Development\\Guides\\ParentFolder', 
parentDirectory: 'ParentFolder' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're `import`, you can import `basename`:

```js
import { dirname, basename } from 'node:path';
const parentName = dirname(basename(filename));
```

Here's [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathbasenamepath-suffix)