# Get parent directory name from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get parent directory name from url using nodejs but not working.  Can anyone find the mistake from my nodejs code? I want to get "rain" instead of "projects".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parent directory name in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956127/get-parent-directory-name-in-node-js)

Comment: Not duplicate..I have checked that answer..that is not working

Comment: @nickzoum : Yes i am expecting rain

Comment: I am getting the output as ```rain```? Your question answers itself

Comment: I am also getting the output as rain.

Answer (score 2):

`Array#pop` will remove and return the last element, you want to get the second from last element. So instead do `[length - 2]`.

```js
var list = "c:/mamp/projects/rain/tree".split("/");
console.log(list[list.length - 2]);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: Can we access the folder?

Comment: const folder = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0];
 return folder;

Comment: @Sitharth I'm confused should the output be `c:/mamp/projects/rain` or just `rain`? How do you want to access the folder?

Comment: Can we access parent folder from workspace folder path?

Comment: Can i return parent folder instead of workspace folder?

Comment: @Sitharth So do you want to get `projects` instead of `rain`?

Comment: @Sitharth Do you mean `__dirname`?

Comment: @Sitharth I'm also working with VSCode why doesn't `__dirname` work for you? What does it print?

Comment: How can i use that? Can you send me an example code?

Comment: @Sitharth Just try `console.log(__dirname)`

Comment: If i use __dirname i am getting vscode extension folder path

Comment: @Sitharth I don't understand how this doesn't work, so I don't think I can help

Comment: You should try getting a bit more reputation to put a bounty on the other question, so that people will answer it. But make sure that it is clear.

Comment: var prevFolder= path.dirname(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri).split(path.sep).pop();

Comment: Simple..above script not working..Can you try from your side? I am not getting parent folder name